# where is the last commit <SHA-1> of subtree repo is stored locally

Tags: git, git-subtree

They say

> git-subtree stores sub-project commit ids and not refs in the meta-data.

That means the command

```
git subtree add --prefix some-split-sub-directory https://some-other-repo-url master --squash
```

will store the SHA-1 of master HEAD on `https://some-other-repo-url` somewhere in the metadata info managed by git.

Now when I run the following command next time

```
git subtree pull --prefix some-split-sub-directory https://some-other-repo-url master --squash
```

git knows the SHA-1 of the last commit on the URL `https://some-other-repo-url` which was merged on the root/parent project and now it fetches/merges the code/commits beyond that last-commit SHA-1.

Now my question is where is this information of last-commit-of-subtree stored inside the local `.git` folder?

How can I see it that against this repo this is the last commit SHA-1 stored and above/beyond this next pull/merge will take place?

I had peeped into the following places like .git/config, .git/refs, but none info found.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find it in .git folder either, but I managed to get it using a function from:
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.sh

AFAICT it parses git history for the latest relevant subtree squash:

```
find_latest_squash () {
    debug "Looking for latest squash ($dir)..."
    dir="$1"
    sq=
    main=
    sub=
    git log --grep="^git-subtree-dir: $dir/*\$" \
        --no-show-signature --pretty=format:'START %H%n%s%n%n%b%nEND%n' HEAD |
    while read a b junk
    do
        debug "$a $b $junk"
        debug "{{$sq/$main/$sub}}"
        case "$a" in
        START)
            sq="$b"
            ;;
        git-subtree-mainline:)
            main="$b"
            ;;
        git-subtree-split:)
            sub="$(git rev-parse "$b^0")" ||
            die "could not rev-parse split hash $b from commit $sq"
            ;;
        END)
            if test -n "$sub"
            then
                if test -n "$main"
                then
                    # a rejoin commit?
                    # Pretend its sub was a squash.
                    sq="$sub"
                fi
                debug "Squash found: $sq $sub"
                echo "$sq" "$sub"
                break
            fi
            sq=
            main=
            sub=
            ;;
        esac
    done
}
```